# Invalid results from SQL Server "NOT IN" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have run a query on our SQL Server 2012 which returned no results. I discovered that this was incorrect and I SHOULD have gotten 16 records. I changed the query and get the answer expected but I am at a loss to understand why my original query did not work as expected.

So my ORIGINAL query which returned no results was:

```
SELECT
    WPB.[ID number]
FROM
    [Fact].[REPORT].[WPB_LIST_OF_IDS] WPB
WHERE
    [ID number] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT IdNumber 
                        FROM MasterData.Dimension.Customer DC)
```

The reworked query is this:

```
SELECT
    WPB.[ID number]
FROM
    [Fact].[REPORT].[WPB_LIST_OF_IDS] WPB
LEFT JOIN
    MasterData.Dimension.Customer DC ON WPB.[ID number] = DC.IdNumber
WHERE
    DC.IdNumber IS NULL
```

Can anyone tell me WHY the first query (which incidentally runs in fractions of a second vs the 2nd which takes a minute) does not work? I don't want to repeat this mistake in the future!

Comment: The second query doesn't work either. If it takes 1 minute it means you are missing indexes - one or both of the `ID` fields aren't indexed. In any case, if you want help with SQL you should provide table schemas, indexes, sample data and desired output. If you want help with performance you should *first* check the execution plan

Comment: NOT IN (select distinct...) distinct is redundand here and can affect performance. Anyway, performance will differ as the queries are logically different. If you don't want to repeat that mistake in the future then DO NOT USE NOT IN in subquery. NEVER!

Comment: BTW `Select distinct IdNumber` causes an unnecessary `DISTINCT` operation. You don't care how many `1` are returned, you only care whether there are *any* or *none*. The query optimizer will either *ignore* that `distinct* or end up performing a useless sort/distinct operation. If *any* `IdNumber` entry in a *Dimension table* is NULL you have a **very** serious problem. Dimensions shouldn't have nulls, they should have *explicit* records for `Missing`, `NotApplicable`, `NotFound` values. Again without schema and data people can only guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `not in` with a subquery.  It doesn't work the way you expect with `NULL` values.  If *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then no rows are returned at all.

Instead, use `not exists`.  This has the semantics that you expect:

```
select wpb.[ID number]
from [Fact].[REPORT].[WPB_LIST_OF_IDS] wpb
where not exists (select 1
                  from MasterData.Dimension.Customer dc
                  where wpb.[ID number] = dc.IdNumber
                 );
```

Of course, the `left join` method also works.

Comment: Gordon  is always few seconds ahead with his answers. Just to explain the NOT IN. It is converted to AND statements, so column NOT IN (value1, value2, NULL) will be translated into (column <> value1 AND column <> value2 AND column <> NULL) so you'll gt TRUE AND TRUE AND FALSE as column <> NULL is always false.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev: To be very, atrociously, nit-pickingly precise: `column <> NULL` is always `UNKNOWN` if `ANSI_NULLS` is `ON` (yes, [`UNKNOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql) -- no, I don't know why they didn't just name this `NULL`). In practice this distinction is irrelevant, because I'm not aware of any context where `UNKNOWN` is not treated the same way as `FALSE`. And, of course, T-SQL has no separate Boolean data type that you could use to store and observe the result.